# User can change app theme

Tags: java, android, eclipse, themes, android-actionbar

i want the user of my app to have the ability to change the applications theme.
Eg, Dark, Light, Light, with dark actionbar and device default. How is this possible, i have a prefrences screen which have a listpref in it, with the four options (shown above). How can i let the user change the app theme?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can do it. I did that in my previous project. But I don't have my working laptop in hand, so I have no way to show you some sample code. That's reason why I just add comment instead of answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is quite easy if you want to use only built-in themes and if you don't need to customize them.

As an example I'll use `ListPreferece` with entry values like this:

```
<string-array name="pref_theme_values" translatable="false">
    <item>THEME_LIGHT</item>
    <item>THEME_DARK</item>
</string-array>
```

Then you can retrieve the selected value by using this method:

```
public int getThemeId(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String theme = settings.getString(context.getResources().getString(R.string.pref_theme_key), null);

    if (theme == null || theme.equals("THEME_LIGHT")) {
        return android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light;
    } else if (theme.equals("THEME_DARK")) {
        return android.R.style.Theme_Holo;
    }

    // default
    return android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light;
}
```

After that you should override the `onCreate` method:

```
// onCreate
this.mCurrentTheme = this.getThemeId(this);
this.setTheme(this.mCurrentTheme);
this.setContentView(...); // should be after the setTheme call
```

And `onStart` method (because you need to refresh the theme as soon as a user has returned from the settigns page)

```
// onStart
int newTheme = this.getThemeId(this);
if(this.mCurrentTheme != newTheme) {
    this.finish();
    this.startActivity(new Intent(this, this.getClass()));
    return;
}
```

Also you need to save the activity state somehow so that the application displays the same data after the activity is restarted.

Comment: How do i define mCurrentTheme? the structur, didnt get it all :/ But thanks!

Comment: @Stian Instebo `private int mCurrentTheme;` inside your activity.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how to do it;

```
 if (prefs.getBoolean("1darkTheme", false)==false){//user has selected dark theme
        setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Holo);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "dark", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "light", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```